# How to make Apache case sensitive on Windows and/or Mac?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, mac, case-sensitive

Is it possible to make Apache serve files in a case sensitive way? I'm having the issue where an accidental capitalization of a letter is not getting caught in my development environment (Windows/Mac), but is causing havoc on staging (Linux).

Is there a way to configure apache to do this? If I could avoid having to run VMs, that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the underlying filesystem. It is possible to create a case-sensitive HFS+ filesystem, but there is no easy solution for Windows.